# Writing to a resource file in android

Tags: android, inputstream, outputstream

I need to keep reading and writing a file while running the application in Android. I can easily read the data with
*InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.appdata);*
and then
*is.close();*
when finished. But how can I write new data to the same file?

Comment: You cannot modify the resource files in android, in order to modify you need to copy the file to your sd card and then try modifying it .

Answer (score 2):

Android resources are read only, you cannot write to them at run time, consider reading your file and copying it to SD card or internal storage, and then edit that file instead.